# how to add class 'ui-btn-active 'on li tag in jquery mobile at runtime

Tags: jquery-mobile, navbar

i am using jQuery Mobile Navigation Tabs. i take a common footer for all pages like footer.html, and load this footer on a footer div at run time. this is working good as i want.

here is my code of footer.html

```
<div data-role="footer" data-id="foo1" data-position="fixed">
<div data-role="navbar">
        <ul id="footertab">

            <li id="home"><a href="#page1" data-transition="none"   data-icon="tab-home"  ></span>Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page2" data-transition="none"  data-icon="tab-alert"   ><span   class="count">6</span>Alerts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page3" data-transition="none" data-icon="tab-services" >Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page4" data-transition="none"  data-icon="tab-learn">Learn</a></li>
            <li><a href="#page5" data-transition="none" data-icon="tab-setting">Settings</a></li>  
        </ul>


    </div><!-- /navbar -->
</div><!-- /footer -->

</div><!-- /page -->
```

And i add this footer on run time using this code.

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function(event){
  $(".addfooter").load('footer.html', function(){
  $(this).trigger("create");

  });

});
```

this running fine. but i have some issue with this code.it does not show the active tab. 
i know that i have to add class='ui-btn-active ui-state-persist' in my selected tab. 
but i do not sure that how to add and replace it with java script. 
i dont want to use to write this footer at all pages.

for this task i use this code in side my script

```
$(document).delegate('[data-role="navbar"] a', 'click', function () {
    alert("calling tab click");
    $(this).addClass('ui-btn-active ui-state-persist');

});
```

This function call every time when i click any tab. but it does show selected tab. 
all tabs are deselected. 
How  can i solve this problem.
please suggest me

Comment: instead of `$(this).trigger("create");` add `$('[data-role=page]').trigger('pagecreate');` and try again.

Comment: this does not work. give some bad effect. adding five li in page contant instand of tab.

Comment: its weird that jqm is refusing to add `ui-btn-active` however, if you copy its style and give it a class name it works. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/68bQK/

Comment: jqm is not refusing to add ui-btn-active. it will active tab. but not those which i clicked. it will be net or previous button or may be randomly. not sure? i think 'pageinit' and 'click' may be conflig?

Comment: `pageinit` fires once, so it wouldn't cause any conflict. What do you mean *but not those which i clicked*.?

Comment: means suppose i click on home button then it will be select Alert or services tab.
always show different selected tab.

Comment: you can something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/vGt2A/

Comment: Thanks now i decide to move on http://jsfiddle.net/3RJuX/ this approach. Do you think this will create some problem on performance?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29606/discussion-between-omar-and-vivek-tiwari)

Answer (score 0):

Hello try this code.

```
$(document).live('pageshow',function(event,ui){
  // disable previous selected links
  $('[data-role=navbar] a').removeClass("ui-btn-active");
  // select link
  var menuLink = $('[data-role=navbar] a[href="#'+$.mobile.activePage.attr('id')+'"]');
  menuLink.addClass("ui-btn-active");
});
```